# How To Authorize The Google Stmpt For Asp.Net.. Got Following Error When I Use

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in
>   System.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("m.@gmail.com", "pssword");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }

Comment: Please edit your question and post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection

Set `EnableSsl` to true.

Comment: smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("m.@gmail.com", "pssword");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);

Comment: Then your password is wrong, or you disabled less-secure apps in account settings.

Comment: is it we use gmail password or we need to do a chages in a ccount??